How to turn off LED in stm32 onn board f103c6t6?
I have started studying stm32. I'm trying to blink LED PC13 on board stm32f103c6t6. I could turn on led, but when i tried to turn it off, it didn't work. The fragment of code is below.
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
        GPIOC->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_ODR13;//turn PC_13 ON
        HAL_Delay(500);
    GPIOC->ODR &= GPIO_ODR_ODR13;//turn PC_13 OFF
    HAL_Delay(500);    
/* USER CODE END WHILE */
  
  }
 


Also i have tried another way, but it havent worked at all. The LED was turnned off. The fragment of code is below.
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    GPIOC->BSRR &=~ GPIO_BSRR_BS13;//turn PC_13 ON
    HAL_Delay(500);
    GPIOC->BSRR &=~ GPIO_BSRR_BS13;//turn PC_13 OFF
    HAL_Delay(500);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }

Also i tried only HAL funnctions(WritePin, TogglePin...), but LED also didn't feel them to turn it off.
while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(500);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(500);
        
  }

Maybe because LED is inverted it isnt't turning off casually.

have you configured the pin as an output? Because if you haven't, no setting the state will do anything. Also look up this question, it's been asked before. you need to set 0 with & and set 1 with |

Yes, i did it in CUbeMx

To set the bit you need to OR
    GPIOC->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR13;//turn PC_13 OFF

BSRR has to be assigned not RMW
    GPIOC->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR13;//turn PC_13 ON

    GPIOC->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS13;//turn PC_13 OFF

